# Where is Club Atlantis in Night City of 2077

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

It appears that Cyberpunk 2077 uses just the one map, even for flashbacks (I once glitched out when entering Johnny's Porsche after leaving the club Atlantis).
But as a directionally challenged person, I am not able to find the location in the regular map of 2077.
Therefore I would like to find out where the club is located.
It should be in Japantown, on Capitola street - I would prefer a map with a "You are here" sticker...

Comment: Do you mean the club called The Afterlife? I'm not sure there is a "Club Atlantis" in 2077. There is one in the table top game Cyberpunk 2020, though.

Comment: Atlantis was used in the flashbacks when you play as Johnny.

Comment: I see, so it's definitely a different place. Not sure if it is still around ~50 years later but if I run into it in-game I'll share what I find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Club Atlantis is closed in Night City 2077, but the building is still there with an unmarked entrance.

[image: Closed exterior of Atlantis]

[image: Location of Atlantis on the game map]

With some cheating, you can "enter" the club.

[image: Female V glitched inside Atlantis]